# COVID Return latest cases/deaths from data without filter

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, calculated-field

I am trying to create a COVID-19 Dashboard in Tableau from the data I have gathered from Google BigQuery COVID dataset. The database was queried to return confirmed cases and deaths for each county ranging from January-Sept 13th. For each date, the active cases and deaths are reported. When trying to visual the Geodata with cases/deaths as labels I am getting values for sum/average which are incorrect due to Tableau taking into account all of the data irrespective of date. [image]I solved this issue by filtering by date and creating a dropdown where the user can select individual date. My question is how can I create a calculated field where it automatically returns the most recent number of active cases/deaths (take the value of the most recent date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an LOD calculation like this: `IF [Date] = {FIXED [County] : MAX([Date])} THEN [Cases] END`

Comment: I understand this is very elegant. Thank you!